# OpenCV set Contour to 0

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, contour

I'm coding with OpenCV in C++. I get from the method

> findContours()

a value stored in 'contours'; 
the datatype is vector>.
I want to set contours[i] to 0; 
`contours[i]=0` doesn't work, because it expects a vector of vectors of points and not a integer. Has anyone an idea how I could 'clear' it?
Thanks!

Comment: You might want to explain what you want to achieve and why you want to do this for people to propose a suitable solution.

Comment: Do you want to draw the contour[i] as black (value 0)?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to do this. I edited my post now for other readers, so that they can understand my question very fast. Hope, this is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findContours()` returns a `vector<vector<Point> >`. That means that contours[i] is a `vector<Point>`. I would hence try

```
contours[i].clear();
```

instead.